# How can I know which fiels cause IntegrityError when inserting into a table with multiple unique fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with multiple unique fields in PostgreSQL. e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    username VARCHAR,
    email    VARCHAR,
    UNIQUE (username),
    UNIQUE (email),
)
```

When I insert into this table using SQLAlchemy, `IntegrityError` may occur. I can catch the exception, but it seems that the exception object doesn't have an attribute or something indicating which field is causing the error.

How can I know which field violates the uniqueness constrain? I know parsing the exception message will work but is there a more elegent way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no magic unfortunately, you'll have to parse the exception string. IntegrityError is just a wrapper for underlying DB-API database operation error, it doesn't do anything fancy.